# php timezone wrong output when passing to another function

Tags: php

Please check two echo and its output. On both place i am passing same value but when i am using server_time_as_per_users_zone() function it just returns wrong information. How can i get similar correct output from first echo? any idea?

```
function distance_finder($_d1,$_d2){
  $d1= new DateTime($_d1);
  $d2= new DateTime($_d2);
  $interval= $d1->diff($d2);
  $r = ($interval->days * 24) + $interval->h;
  return $r;
}

function server_time_as_per_users_zone($users_zone){
  $dateTime = new DateTime('now', new DateTimeZone($users_zone));
  $date1 = $dateTime->format("d-m-y h:m:sa");
  return $date1;
}

echo distance_finder("15-04-2017 01:33:26pm", server_time_as_per_users_zone('Asia/Dhaka')); //Output is: 17487
echo distance_finder("15-04-2017 01:33:26pm","16-04-2017 02:33:29pm"); //Output is: 25 which is correct
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to format with `Y`, not `y` (the former return 4 digit year, the latter 2 digit year). So the correct function would be this:

```
function server_time_as_per_users_zone($users_zone){
 $dateTime = new DateTime('now', new DateTimeZone($users_zone));
 $date1 = $dateTime->format("d-m-Y h:m:sa");
 return $date1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes

Just replace y to Y

using y

$date1 = $dateTime->format("d-m-y h:m:sa");

you will get 15-04-**17** 11:04:16pm

with Y

you will get 15-04-**2017** 11:04:16pm

And it will works fine.